Wrapping content screen in Swift UI
I would like to creat a screen in SwiftUi which should be displayed using the Coordinator pattern (old navigation system). The screen should wrap the content but if the content is too big, expand to fill the entire screen and also allow scrolling.
I was able to come up with this but it does not wrap the content, instead filling the entire screen
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct ModalScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @ViewBuilder private var content: () -> Content
    private let showsIndicators: Bool

    public init(
        showsIndicators: Bool = true,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators
        self.content = content
    }

    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var viewSize: CGSize = .zero

    public var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            scrollViewWithContent()
                .scrollDisabled(
                    contentSize.height <= viewSize.height
                )
        } else {
            scrollViewWithContent()
        }
    }

    private func scrollViewWithContent() -> some View {
        ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
            VStack {
                content()
                    .readSize(in: $contentSize)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(minHeight: contentSize.height)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .readSize(in: $viewSize)
    }
}



You might want to investigate ViewThatFits
